# How to change the background color of a SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, ios9, sfsafariviewcontroller

I understand that the code below changes the SFSafariViewController's tint color, but how do you change the background color of the navbar and tabBar?

```
SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:webpageUrl];
[safariViewController.view setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

To clarify I want to change the semi-transparent white color to dark green?

[image]

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SFSafariViewController`, as of iOS 10 SDK, has the `preferredBarTintColor` and `preferredControlTintColor` properties to control the tint color of bar items and the bars themselves, respectively.

Comment: Is there any way to turn off the translucency?

Comment: @Happiehappie I don't think that's possible. Open an enhancement request with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with the current SFSafariViewController implementation in iOS 9.0. A radar is filed under http://www.openradar.me/22947521